# Facebook Unity SDK version 5.0.3 beta feedback and questions

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Summary of issues and questions using: Using SDK 5.0.3, Build 140124.4c900f79fb0ada4

The following occur in the Unity Editor.

1) Issue 1 Finished loading Facebook dll, but could not find version info

Using SDK 5.0.3, Build 140124.4c900f79fb0ada4

```
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FbDebug:Info(String)
FB:Init(InitDelegate, String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, HideUnityDelegate,         String) (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:131)
FB:Init(InitDelegate, HideUnityDelegate, String) (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:84)
FacebookManager:CallFBInit(Action`1) (at Assets/Scripts/Facebook/FacebookManager.cs:66)
MainMenuHandler:drawMainMenu() (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/MainMenuHandler.cs:125)
MainMenuHandler:OnGUI() (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/MainMenuHandler.cs:95)

loading dll: https://integrated-plugin-canvas-    rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.0/CanvasFacebook.dll
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FbDebug:Log(String)
<LoadFacebookClass>c__Iterator5:MoveNext() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:341)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
Facebook.EditorFacebook:OnAwake() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/EditorFacebook.cs:35)
Facebook.AbstractFacebook:Awake()
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
Facebook.FBComponentFactory:GetComponent(IfNotExist)
Facebook.EditorFacebookLoader:get_fb() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/EditorFacebookLoader.cs:13)
CompiledFacebookLoader:Start() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:417)


Finished loading Facebook dll, but could not find version info
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
FbDebug:Warn(String)
FB:OnDllLoaded() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:163)
CompiledFacebookLoader:Start() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:418)
```

2) Issue 2 Often get (but not always) Resolving host timed out even though my Internet connection is ok

```
Resolving host timed out: integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
<LoadFacebookClass>c__Iterator5:MoveNext() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:346)
```

QUESTION : For issue 2, can this error occur on mobile? How can I trap this error to handle it properly in my app?

3) Issue 3 QUESTION: can my app somehow subscribe to AppRequests so I can get them automatically in my app or do I need to poll Facebook every X seconds by going a FB.API("/me/apprequests” …) ?

4) Issue 4 - Cannot launch AppRequestAsFriendSelector in Unity Editor (but works well on mobile)

```
FacebookManager-CallAppRequestAsFriendSelector called successfully.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FacebookManager:CallAppRequestAsFriendSelector(String, String, String, String, String, String)     (at Assets/Scripts/Facebook/FacebookManager.cs:186)
PopupHandler:askLifeFB() (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/PopupHandler.cs:231)
PopupHandler:drawButton(GUIContent, Action) (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/PopupHandler.cs:465)
PopupHandler:renderAskFriendsLife() (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/PopupHandler.cs:222)
PopupHandler:showPopup(Int32) (at Assets/Scripts/Menus/PopupHandler.cs:163)
UnityEngine.GUI:CallWindowDelegate(WindowFunction, Int32, GUISkin, Int32, Single, Single, GUIStyle)

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

at Facebook.FriendSelectorDialog+FriendList.SetCustomFilters (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 filters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Facebook.FriendSelectorDialog.OnInit () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Facebook.FbSkinnedDialog.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Facebook.NativeDialog.ShowDialog[FriendSelectorDialog] (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 paramsDict, Facebook.FacebookDelegate callback, Facebook.ErrorDelegate errorCallback) [0x00000] in :0 
    UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
    FbDebug:Error(String)
    Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
    Facebook.NativeDialog:ShowDialog(Dictionary`2, FacebookDelegate, ErrorDelegate)
    Facebook.AsyncRequestFriendSelectorGet:ShowDialog(FBResult)
    Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogGet:CheckAndShowDialog(FBResult)
    Facebook.c__Iterator0:MoveNext()

```
External Call: fbUi("{\"message\":\"Help me unlock the next     episode!\",\"filters\":null,\"data\":\"Ask_Give_Life,1\",\"title\":\"App     Requests\",\"app_id\":\"1375338362720935\",\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"method\":\"apprequests\"}", "1");
UnityEngine.Application:ExternalCall(String, Object[])
Facebook.CanvasFacebook:JSFallbackUI(String, Dictionary`2, FacebookDelegate)
Facebook.FallbackData:JSFallback(String)
Facebook.NativeDialog:ShowDialog(Dictionary`2, FacebookDelegate, ErrorDelegate)
Facebook.AsyncRequestFriendSelectorGet:ShowDialog(FBResult)
Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogGet:CheckAndShowDialog(FBResult)
```

5) Otherwise great job! Thank you so much for improving Facebook integration in Unity. So much easier to test now that we can get a token in the Editor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We will look into #1 and #2.  For #3, we generally think of app requests as a way to get users into your game.  As such, there isn't a way to subscribe to them in the game.  For #4, what filters are you trying to set for the friend selector?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report.  Like Ben said we'll look into #1 & #2.

For #3 Best practice is to have a menu that a player can get to manage their requests.  That way you don't have to poll X seconds and only update from there.

To expand on #4, a custom filter should be a json string like so:
`["all", {"name":"my filter", "user_ids":[<facebook_user_id>, <another_facebook_user_id>]}]` when called with `FB.AppRequest()`.  We have special defined key names like `all`, `app_users` that can go in the list.  More custom filters should be in the form of a json object with two keys: `name` and `user_ids` with name being the list's name that is shown and the user_ids being the list of facebook user ids to put in there.

Thanks for the feedback and I hope this helps.

Comment: Good news, #4 is fixed by setting, filters : "[\"all\"]" Thanks!

Comment: PS: #6 issue - You can see the "title" you passed as a parameter in the App Requests window launched by the Editor, but on the mobile device, the title is always "App Requests".

Comment: #1 is still happening.